# SFML compile run missing dll

Tags: mingw, sublimetext, sfml

I have problem with compile a single script.
I use SublimeText and MinGW compiler. I input all SFML library.

This is code:

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>

using namespace sf;

    int main()
    {
        RenderWindow window(VideoMode(453,453),"Sachy");

        Texture t1;
        t1.loadFromFile("images/figures.png");

        Sprite s(t1);

        while(window.isOpen())
        {
            Event e;
            while(window.pollEvent(e))
            {
                if(e.type == Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }
            window.clear();
            window.draw(s);
            window.display();
        }
    }
```

And in cmd.exe i run:

```
g++ main.cpp -static-libgcc -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Compile with no errors. When a try to launch a.exe this error show:

```
The code could not be started because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll was not found. Try to resolve this problem by reinstalling the program
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the shared GCC runtime by default, as such your compiled executable will depend on it, which you can find in MinGW's `bin` directory.

If you don't want to copy these libraries, you can use the static runtime instead, by adding the following two options to your command line:

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Note that this will increase the size of your resulting binary.

Comment: I try this: g++ main.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system and still same problem.

Comment: @ATomas My guess would be your SFML depending on it as well. If you've built from source there's a CMake variable for that, can't remember it right now.

Comment: If you use static library you will need the `-D SFML_STATIC` option as well